# Mapping all properties of 'X' type with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, lambda, automapper

I've just started using AutoMapper and so far found it very straight-forward and time-saving.

Just one thing I'm not sure about - how do I map all the properties of a given type in the same way?

Can this be done with AutoMapper in a single statement, using a lambda, as with regular mapping?

Comment: try this one http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/, it was designed to map from all props of a specific type to another one in the first place

Comment: Thanks for that @Omu. Why don't you add that as an Answer?

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is known as a `CustomTypeConverter`.  These are global in scope, and only need to be configured once.

The syntax is:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TSourceProperty,TDestinationProperty>().ConvertUsing(argument);
```

where `argument` can be

1. An implementation of `ITypeConverter<TSourceProperty,TDestinationProperty>`
2. A `Func<TSourceProperty,TDestinationProperty>`

Jimmy Bogard has an article on implementing `CustomTypeConverter`s at  http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/05/05/automapper-feature-custom-type-converters.aspx .

More information is also provided in the [CustomTypeConverter page of the AutoMapper documentation](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters&referringTitle=Home).

Oh, and by the way (since I want Omu's bounty) you can also do this by **switching to valueinjecter**.

Comment: it's not really the same, if you would need different algorithms for converting from int to Foo for more mappings (probably you would have to call CreateMap each time before mapping), or if you would to need map from all types that inherit a certain base class to int, how would you do that

Comment: You only need a single call to `CreateMap` per application instance.  If you need to make `int` map to `Foo` differently in different contexts, then you should declare it as a property-based mapping instead of a type-based mapping.  In these cases, you can use [Custom Value Resolvers](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Value%20Resolvers&referringTitle=Home) to specify complicated `int` to `Foo` mappings, and just make the declaration `Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ForMember(dest => dest.Total, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());`

Comment: @Omu, to map all the types that inherit a certain base class, you can use reflection to get all the derived types and then loop through them and call `CreateMap`.  This can be costly and should probably be done in your IoC configuration, but the static call would look something like `void MapSubTypes<TBase,TDestination>(){foreach(var subType in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof (TBase).IsAssignableFrom(t)))){ Mapper.CreateMap(subType,typeof(TDestination));}`  .  Forgive me if I made a syntax error - its hard to code in the comment box

Comment: well this is a big difference between the two technologies, automapper is very rigid and you have to write a lot of configuration for any tiny thing, and you have all of these configs used for all you map calls plus the built-in (flattening Get + Method to prop, etc) whether you need it or not.

Comment: @Omu, I think AutoMapper is great, but I've never used your product.  You sound very confident in it.  I will have to give it a try, so I can make an honest comparison.